# Unable to set LastModifiedDate when creating records in bulk inside a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, audit-fields

I've enabled "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" permission on a permset (as per [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000334139)).

Inserting it via:

> sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s MyNS__Some_Record__c -f invs.csv -i Id -w 5

Getting:

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE:Unable to create/update fields: LastModifiedDate. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.:LastModifiedDate --

Answer (score 2):

It sure looks like the Bulk API doesn't currently support "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" at the moment based on experimental results. I suspect that's an oversight. I'll ask.

Answer (score 0):

@dzh - You need two levels of setup for this to work and you have done only one.

- User Interface Setting - This is org level setup needed before you give permission to Profile or Perm set
- Profile or Perm set permission - After enabling User Interface setting now go ahead and add the permission to the profile or Permset

If you skip step 1 and do the step 2, although you add the permission in profile/permset the audit fields are not editable. I faced the same issue before checking out the documents

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334139&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer anything. First setting just hides second one - you can't add that permission before enabling globally. Just tried same steps on a fresh scratch org and no bueno.

Comment: Tried with adding setting for profile as well as permset (which took way longer than needed - can't change sysadmin profile of default user) - that didn't help at all...

Comment: Data point:  In early 2020, I just successfully used the bulk API _(through the Python "Simple Salesforce" package)_ to upsert Task records with `LastModifiedDate` and `CreatedDate` set to dates in the past after getting my user permissions right.  _(That said, I'm having trouble with `ActivityDate` making bulk loads fail.)_